# How to add checkbox image in eclipse e4?

Tags: eclipse, checkbox, jface, e4

I am using eclipse e4. I need to add an image for checkbox(checked and unchecked). I have tried adding the image in the following way in table viewer. I can see only red spots in place of the image.

I have  used the following code snippet.

```
private void createCheckedImage() {
    Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(ColumnLabelProvider.class);
    URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("icons/checkbox_yes.png"), null);
    ImageDescriptor imageDcr = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);
    CHECKED = imageDcr.createImage();
  }
```

I am not sure whether I am doing it correct. Can anyone suggest some ideas?

Comment: Code looks OK. Is the icons directory included in the build.properties?

Comment: yes.. Its included in the build.properties

Answer (score 1):

The answer to my question is the small mistake that I have done in FrameworkUtil.getBundle() method. I have added **ColumnLabelProvider.class** but It should be the class that I am using. My class name is StatisticsPart. So it should be like the following code snippet

```
private void createCheckedImage() {
    Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(StatisticsPart.class);
    URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("icons/checkbox_yes.png"), null);
    ImageDescriptor imageDcr = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);
    CHECKED = imageDcr.createImage();
  }
```